# Can't setTypeface on a Button - NOT NullPointerException, but typeface never changes in program

Tags: java, android, user-interface, fonts

I have been trying for a while, and searching around a lot to figure this out, but no luck.
My problem is, in a nutshell: I can't set the Typeface of my Button programmatically. I can get it just fine with findViewById, and then I create my Typeface, and set it, nothing breaks everything seems normal. Except the change never shows up in the program. Its still the default typeface.

Here's my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Button lcb;
Typeface resoLite;
private SplashFragment splashFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, splashFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        splashFragment = (SplashFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("resocializer");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "titillium-bold"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setTitle(s);


        //Here's the important stuff. I get the button fine. I create the typeface                         
        //fine. I set the typeface fine. but none of this appears to have any effect
        //in the actual program when it's running.
    lcb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lcb);
    resoLite = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/titillium-bold.otf");
        lcb.setTypeface(resoLite);
}
```

And my activity_main xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lcb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lcbText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="#C4A649"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="logConversation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tested the setTypeface with Logs and Typeface.equals() to check if it is setting to what I expect it to and it appears to be so. It just never changes in the actual button on the screen. I feel like there is something obvious I am missing. Any ideas?

EDIT: To be clear, I am trying to set the typeface to a custom font in my assets/fonts/ folder in the project, so setting it in the xml file won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First place your font in the folder **assets/fonts/your_font.ttf**

Now in your Activity/Fragment class add these lines of code :

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font.ttf");
Button custom_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
custom_btn.setTypeface(myTypeface);
custom_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```